# É possível alterar o a cor do background de um elemento para impressão?

Tags: html, css

É possível alterar o background de um elemento na folha de estilo de impressão?
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#dddddd" class="cinza" nowrap="">Seu Nome<br>
<div align="right" class="campo">Eu Sou o João</div>
</td>
```

- Utilizei o `bgcolor="#dddddd"`, não deu certo.
- Utilizei como estilo `<style>`:

---

```
<style media="print">
.cinza{background-color:#dddddd !important;}
</style>
```

Também não deu certo.

> É possível ou não é possível alterar o a cor do background de um elemento para impressão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, se um usuário marcou nas opções algo parecido com "Imprimir imagens e cores de fundo" (vai depender do navegador), nenhum CSS irá sobrescrever isso. Então sempre leve isso em conta.

Mas tem algumas soluções, para os diversos problemas que podem aparecer, que podem ajudar nesses diversos casos:

```
body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  background-color:#dddddd  !important;
}
```

Comment: Isso vai funcionar somente para o [Chrome e Safari 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust).

Comment: Vou testar @Mr. Felix

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@media) para aplicar estilos específicos para impressão:

```
/*CSS para impressão*/
@media print {
  body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}
   .cinza{ background-color:#dddddd  !important; }
}
```

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu bem a pergunta :/
Está funcionando quando coloco outras coisas, como `display:`, `padding:`, etc... Apenas `background-color:` não funciona.

Comment: Aparentemente é devido uma configuração do [Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color). Editei a resposta com uma marcação que funciona para Chorme.