# Dificuldade para se resgatar informações de FILIAL dado um PRODUTO, relacionamento muitos para muitos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Iniciei recentemente meus estudos na área e estou com uma dificuldade no código.

Preciso exibir os dados da seguinte forma:

- Código do produto
- Classe do produto
- Descrição do produto
- Nome da filial onde tem o produto
- Disponibilidade (que se existir na tabela estoque ficará verde, caso contrario vermelho)

Abaixo segue os dados das tabelas e colunas que preciso utilizar

**db_produto**

> CODIGO, CLASSE, DESCRICAO

**db_estoque**

> COD_FILIAL, CODIGO_PRODUTO

**db_filial**

> COD_FILIAL, NOME_FILIAL

Esse é *meu* código **COMPLETO**

```
<?php

 //tabela

 echo "<table border=1>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Codigo</th>";
 echo "<th>Descrição</th>";
 echo "<th>Classe</th>";
 echo "<th>Disponibilidade</th>";
 echo "</tr>";

//conexão

 $strcon =  mysqli_connect('localhost','s.o','b.7','s.a') or die ('Erro');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_produto";

$resultado = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die('erro bd');

//resultados loop

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
$codigo = $registro['CODIGO'];
$descricao = $registro['DESCRICAO'];
$classe = $registro['CLASSE'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$codigo;"</td>";
echo "<td>".$descricao;"</td>";
echo "<td>".$classe;"</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

// fim while 

mysqli_close($strcon);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Esse código não tem nada a ver com o que eu postei. Fica dificil desta forma  copie e cole meu código é o erro que esta acontecendo, juntamente com a criacao do arquivo conn.php

Comment: Editei minha resposta comparando o codigo da tabela db_produto com o codigo_produto da tabela db_estoque

Comment: Agora funcionou, sera que você poderia me dizer como isso funciona? Alguns caracteres ficaram com esse simbolo �, para que eu possa sinalizar com qualquer caractere no campo disponibilidade, onde preciso fazer a alteração?

Comment: Alexandra, tem uma resposta aqui falando dos caracteres estranhos... creio que o resto de sua dúvida atual tenha sido sanado com a resposta do @Victor, correto? Esses caracteres é digno de outra pergunta, não dessa atual

Comment: Sim, vou pesquisar.. obgd

Comment: Encontrei a pergunta que eu tinha em mente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43193/64969; não conheço outra desse contexto aqui o SOpt. Se não ajudar... o botão de nova pergunta está bem ali #hue

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Obrigada, consegui resolver

Comment: @Alexandra, conseguiu resolver de qual forma ficou seu result ?

Comment: @Alexandra, tentei tornar o título mais adequado à proposta da comunidade

Comment: @Victor Sim, deu certo, testei e os dados tambem estão corretos com o BD!

Comment: Fico feliz em conseguir ter ajudado, qualquer duvida estamos ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom você necessitará de utilizar o `JOIN` imagino que sanará sua dúvida, e também poderá colocar tudo dentro do `while` assim preenchendo a tabela com os registros que serão exibidos do banco de dados, n coluna `Disponibilidade` eu coloquei o campo `nome_filial` para preencher mas, você pode alterar, coloquei apenas para você analisareste código.

Siga o arquivo de conexão e coloque o nome dele de **conn.php**

conn.php

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "nomedoseubanco";

    // Criando a conexão com o banco de dados
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Checando a conexão com o banco de dados
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
?>
```

Também tem alteração no código abaixo

```
<table class="display example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>    
        <tr>
            <th>Código do Produto</th>
            <th>Classe</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Filial</th>
            <th>Disponibilidade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
              include ("conn.php");

                $result = "SELECT A.codigo, A.classe, A.descricao, B.cod_filial, C.nome_filial FROM DB_PRODUTO A"
                        . " LEFT OUTER JOIN DB_ESTOQUE B ON (A.codigo = B.codigo_produto)"
                        . " LEFT OUTER JOIN DB_FILIAL C ON (B.cod_filial = C.cod_filial) ORDER BY A.codigo";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

                $row = array();

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

                    echo "<tr class='btn-default'>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['codigo'] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['classe'] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['descricao'] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['cod_filial'] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $row['nome_filial'] ."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigada @Victor, coloquei o codigo de conexão, mas apresenta o erro  Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Alterei novamente colocando a conexão diretamente sem o include, e alterei o nome da variavel mas printou o erro entre aspas simples $resultado = mysqli_query($strcon,$result) or die('erro');

Comment: Estranho ter dado esse primeiro erro... Já tentou rodar a consulta diretamente no MySQL? Sem passar pelo PHP?

Comment: Sim, fiz a consulta no Mysql ele funciona normalmente, fiz direto no Mysql

Comment: vou alterar e colocar um arquivo de conexão, você altera o nome do banco de dados e sua senha ok ?

Comment: coloquei o arquivo de conexão, siga os passos, aqui esta funcionando perfeitamente,caso não funcione creio que sei PHP deve estar desatualizado. Tente não fazer alteração, afinal o código já está adaptado para atender sua necessidade

Comment: Fiz as alterações, criei outros arquivos, porem aparece   Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in , isso pode ser o PHP?

Comment: Meu php esta na versão 5.5

Comment: Verifique se o erro e realmente nesta query ou em outra acima que venha antes dessa. Caso contrario, Atualize para o php7 e cole este código que dara certo, este php 5.5 so funciona com mysql, que na versão 7.0 se descontinuou e não funciona por isso indico mysqli

Comment: Atualizei, mas mesmo assim continua o mesmo erro, tinha alguns erros de acentuação que foi resolvido com a atualização, porém Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Ocorre o seguinte Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$resultado' (T_VARIABLE) e adicionando o ; , volta para o mesmo erro

Comment: Edite a pergunta colocando a estrutura das suas tabelas com os registros, e o código editado junto com o arquivo de conexao

Answer (score 0):

Produto se liga com estoque que se liga com filial. Pelo menos é isso que o nome das colunas indica, mnemonicamente.

Para aceitar produtos que não estão em estoques, de lembre sempre do gráfico de sql join, veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118352/64969). No caso, queremos o que o autor da imagem identificou como **two LEFT OUTTER JOINS**.

Aplicando o mesmo formato da imagem para o seu caso:

```
SELECT p.*, f.nome_filial
FROM
  db_produto p
    LEFT JOIN db_estoque e ON p.codigo = e.codigo_produto
    LEFT JOIN db_filial f ON e.cod_filial = f.cod_filial
```

Depois de resgatar essa informação seria tratar para exibição. No caso, nomes de filial nulos deveriam não ser exibidos na tabela e, também, deveriam por uma cor vermelha na coluna de disponibilidade. Caso fosse não nulo, só exibir o valor na coluna adequada e verde na coluna de disponibilidade.

Acima, o tratamento de qual cor exibir ficaria no PHP. Dá para jogar no banco? Sim, é possível. Nesse caso, vamos retornar na consulta uma nova coluna (vamos chamar ela genericamente de `cor_disponibilidade`?), onde será retornada cor em RGB para depois só aplicar no CSS (mais sobre isso aqui: [É possível alterar o a cor do background de um elemento para impressão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172777/64969)).

No caso, para jogar no banco, vamos verificar se o valor do código da filial é nulo e retornar `#ff0000` para ausência, ou `#00ff00` para disponibilidade. A estrutura é basicamente a mesma:

```
SELECT p.*, isnull(f.nome_filial, '') as nome_filial,
    CASE
      WHEN e.cod_filial IS NULL THEN '#ff0000'
      ELSE '#00ff00'
    END as cor_disponibilidade
FROM
  db_produto p
    LEFT JOIN db_estoque e ON p.codigo = e.codigo_produto
    LEFT JOIN db_filial f ON e.cod_filial = f.cod_filial
```

Comment: Obrigada por disponibilizar a imagem, entendi as possibilidades do join, eu substitui, mas deu erro, meu codigo completo é esse, como ficaria?  mas ele acusa o erro de BD esse aqui, $resultado = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die('erro bd');

Comment: eu usei a mesma variavel e so coloquei o codigo aqui, $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_produto";

Comment: @Alexandra vou ficar te devendo um código mais completo, foquei a resposta no SQL que era onde aparentava ser a sua maior dificuldade. Responder pelo celular implica em ser difícil fazer o teste na linguagem propriamente dita. Quando estiver no computador coloco no PHP direitinho

Comment: Mas o erro foi de sintaxe? Ou foi outro erro? Tendo o erro posso tentar melhorar a consulta ou dar uma dica

Comment: Obigada, foi um erro no mysqli_query, sim e minha maior dificuldade, eu vou tentar novamente, e se possível aguardo sua ajuda

Comment: @Alexandra você pretende correr o seu while com quais campos para preenchera os campos filial e disponibilidade ?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tentarei utilizar as cores, obrigada Jefferson!

Comment: @Alexandra , tem certeza que a minha resposta foi a mais adequada a chegar na solução do seu problema? Eu tive a impressão de ter sido a do Victor